# Why my test is throwing Exception-Unable to locate element in webdriver?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

```
package testproject;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
  public class mytestclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       WebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        Driver.get("https://www.gmail.com/");
         WebElement wb= Driver.findElement(By.name("Email"));
         wb.sendKeys("sweta");
         WebElement wb1= Driver.findElement(By.name("Passwd"));
         wb1.sendKeys("123456");
         WebElement wb2= Driver.findElement(By.id("signIn"));
         wb2.click();
         WebElement wb3= Driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/a"));
         wb3.click();
         WebElement wb4= Driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71"));
         wb4.click();
   }
}
```

When i am executing this code everything is going fine till the point where i want the sign in button to be clicked. I am getting exception which says that 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/a"} but when i am trying to locate it using fierbug its working fine. 
In the above mentioned code i changed the email id and password to keep the email safe.

I was facing problem with one more program which i already posted on stakwave so if u can then please have a look at this link-[webdriver is not able to click on a hyperlink in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018649/webdriver-is-not-able-to-click-on-a-hyperlink-in-fierfox)

Comment: I would offer two suggestions. 1) A piece of advice, which is that most people go through the process of physically logging into Gmail to have their tests check an email was sent correctly, but this is unneeded as there are *many* libraries out there that can login to Gmail and return the inboxes & messages without the need for a physical browser. 2) If you *absolutely must* physically go to Gmail, which I think you don't, then use the "Basic mode"...it's HTML is much more simplier (though still complex) but will give you a better chance.

Comment: @arran Sorry i did't get this-what is "Basic mode"?

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/15049?hl=en ...but as I say, I highly, highly, highly, doubt you even need to bother logging into Gmail but you've not explained your use cases or context very well. May I also suggest to not create many StackOverflow questions. You will end up confusing us *and* yourself. One problem at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain your page is completely loaded after you sign in?

Did you set a timeout for your webdriver? (how long it has to wait for elements). Probably it reads your html before it's completey loaded.

```
Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

To find out quickly if this is the problem do `Thread.sleep(8000)` after you do `wb2.click();`

Comment: No this is not the problen because i already tried Thread.sleep for 3000 miliseconds. But it won't worked.

Comment: sure it is long enough? In my experience it can take some time for slower applications.
If the website is online maybe you can give a link

Comment: I am not able to signIn. Don't know the reason

Comment: Sorry Charlie i did't get it which link you want me to share? When i tried driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS); i got a new exception which says that Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

Comment: from the website you are testing. if it is online

Comment: This is the link of the website for which i was preparing the test -https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1

Comment: Charlie this is the exact massage which i am getting---Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/a"}
Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds

Comment: Its not logging in and it remains on the same window till the time eclipse generates Exception

Comment: Do you have the new GMail login page? like this: http://cdn.ndtv.com/tech/images/Google-newlogin-page.jpg
I don't see any alement with id='gb' on that page

Comment: once you are able to logIn then you will get the email page. If you check the source code of that page then you will get the id=gb. But i am struggling at the logging page itself

Comment: I don't understand you entirely. You want to click ".//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/‌​a" but are still on the login page.
Are you able to click this one? By.id("signIn")

Comment: @ charlie No i am not able to click By.id("signIn"). Did the code is running on your system?

Comment: Don't know why the same code is running on your system without any modification done by you. Is there any thing you can suggest or which you can think of might be the reason because of which the code is not running on my system?

Comment: on your computer, are you using correct password and username?
The only time I get your exception is when I use incorrect login values

Comment: @ charlie yes i am using the login credentials. Any other suggetion?

Comment: maybe one more thing to check: which Firefox version and which Selenium version are you using? Make sure you use the last Selenium release (2.39)

Comment: I am using Selenium version(2.39.0)

Comment: firefox version which i am using is 26.0

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dot at the beginning of your xpath expression. That way you have an xpath expression thaty could match everything. With the dot at the beginning you might retrict yourself depending on if the current node is the root node or not. Ther eis no way to know it. Just the fact the dot can only give you trouble. Unfortunately you cannot always trust what tools like firebug give you (it is still true in 99% of the case).

Of course, ensure that the elemetns you are targeting are already on the screen as suggested by the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem,
issue resolved after setting timeout.

```
Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Not sure whats the role of timeout here though.

Comment: This setting helped me.

Answer (score 0):

remove the dot(.) and star(*) from the xpath and give proper tag name in place of star.

for example if @id=gb is the id of div element, place div in place of star.
Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
//launch browser 
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options); 
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//gmail login :
driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("****",Keys.ENTER);
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("***",Keys.ENTER);
//logout:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/a/span")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign out")).click();
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to elaborate on your answer. Thanks.