# webdriver is not able to click on a hyperlink in firefox

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
package testproject;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class WeblinkTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // Creating a fierfox driver/window
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    //Assigning address of the webpage which you want to check
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    //Creating and Identifing--By.xpath the element on which you want testing
    WebElement wb1= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]"));
    wb1.click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

}
```

Today i was trying to test a gmail link which is available on Google homepage(www.google.co.in). I am able to launch a fierfox window and also it is able to do the first step which is taking me to google homepage but after that nothing is happening neither i am getting any run time error or any  exception from eclipse. Don't know what is going on with the webdriver. 
I was facing problem with one more program which i already posted on stakwave so if u can then please have a look at this link-[Why my test is throwing Exception-Unable to locate element in webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998375/why-my-test-is-throwing-exception-unable-to-locate-element-in-webdriver)

Comment: Have you verified that the `WebElement` you get from Fearfox is still the correct one? Web pages tend to change over night.

Comment: @zapl ya i had verified it with the help of firebug and selenium ie(Both firefox addon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have posted this question in Jan saying that the web-driver was not able to click on the hyperlink and just now i got the solution.
Actually the xpath for the hyperlink was not accurate.
I had used this xpath-
       .//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2] 
which was locating the logo but not the button.

Today i changed it by 
      .//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a 
and now its working absolutely fine.

Please don't be angry on me because i was going through the questions which i had asked from the forum and found this question. I got the solution for the problem thats why i am sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below. It should work

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElement(By.LinkText("Gmail"))
elements.get(0).click().
```

Comment: @A Paul I have posted this question in Jan saying that the web-driver was not able to click on the hyperlink and just now i got the solution. Actually the xpath for the hyperlink was not accurate. I had used this xpath- .//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2] which was locating the logo but not the button.

Today i changed it by .//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a and now its working absolutely fine.

Please don't be angry on me because i was going through the questions which i had asked from the forum and found this question. I got the solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try with implimentig implicit wait after driver initializes. by adding below line
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: i did it but still got the same result that is nothing  is happening after launching the window     WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: Try this out driver.findElement(By.LinkText("Gmail")).click();

Comment: its showing error in "findelement". Don't know why its happening. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

The XPATH in the code is DIV element but you want to click on ANCHOR Gmail So update the xpath for ANCHOR and click on it.

Comment: Sorry but i am not familiar with the "ANCHOR" term. Can you please give me the path which you are asking me to update

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a"));

Comment: i am using driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a")); code only but the end result same i.e, that is after launching the browser nothing happening

Comment: I have tested the code with my said changes i.e adding anchor and its working dear

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the below code,it clicks on GMAIL link on google page,if your question is solved then select as answer

```
WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
WebElement wb1= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a"));
wb1.click();
```

Comment: Sorry buddy but don't know why the code is not working on my system. I can feel the agitation you was having at the time of writing the comment and its totaly fine for me because yesterday also i was facing the same problem. Don't know why codes are running fine on other systems.

Comment: Its ok.Have u face any exception during execution of the code ??

Comment: Can you provide the library detail with version mean selenium and firefox jar version

Comment: Version i can get but don't know how to provide library details. Fierfox version is 26.0 and selenium version is 2.39.0.

Comment: I dnt know what is u using to resolve the dependency of the library.I am using maven to resolve dependency,if u just adding the jar to ur classpath then download the jar from mvn repository.Below is the maven dependency                                        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
      <version>2.30.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.webdriver</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdriver-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.7089</version>
      </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Gmail"))).click();
```

Comment: @A Paul I have posted this question in Jan saying that the web-driver was not able to click on the hyperlink and just now i got the solution. Actually the xpath for the hyperlink was not accurate. I had used this xpath- .//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2] which was locating the logo but not the button.

Today i changed it by .//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a and now its working absolutely fine.

Please don't be angry on me because i was going through the questions which i had asked from the forum and found this question. I got the solution for the problem.