# Does execution of a Java code written to test a webpage using webdriver depends on system?

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, selenium, windows-xp

Actually the question sounds very stupid but I was force to ask this because from yesterday i am trying to test some google web pages but the codes written in Java were stop responding at some certain point. Some time I receive Exception and some time some time getting no result(also don't get any compilation error or any Exception).

My main concern for asking the question is that the same code(without making any change by members) which is not running on my system is running fine on other statckoverflow members systems.

I am posting the links of those two tests which are not executing on my system but others are executing it. See the links here [1st Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998375/why-my-test-is-throwing-exception-unable-to-locate-element-in-webdriver) and [2nd Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018649/webdriver-is-not-able-to-click-on-a-hyperlink-in-firefox)

Comment: Is your network "reliable"?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch yes the network is reliable

Comment: The execution of the webpage depends on the browser on the machine; your question is very difficult to answer because the issue might be on your machine, on your network, on your transit network or (possibly) on Google's network.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Anything you want me to check which in turn rectify my problem

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue consistently?

Comment: what version of webdriver/firefox are you using?

Comment: @Elliott Frisch It happening every time whenever i am running the code. Some time eclipse throws some exception some time i get nothing i.e, neither the expected result nor any exception

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Webdriver version-2.39.0 and Fierfox version-26.0

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Had you found any solution?

Comment: Try a few `tracert` (or `traceroute`) to the host.

Comment: Its very tough for me to do tracert but anyways i really appreciated help your help

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Its very tough for me to do tracert but anyways i really appreciated help your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it not depends on your system but yes it depends on the jdk which is installed on your system. After doing a lot of research for my question i came to know that the webdriver code written in java does't not respond or run according to the system specification but it runs according to the web browser which you are using (firefox, chrom or ie)